# Ionic android app - two apps won't coexist

Tags: android, ionic-framework, deployment

I've created two small android apps using ionic and the both are individually different.  However I don't seem to be able to install both at once.  When I install the second it removes or overwrites the first one.

I first noticed this in debug mode but I've since signed these apps and copied the apk files to device but they still won't coexist.

As I'm using standard Ionic scaffolding it's possible they both have the same ID but I've changed the names in config.xml. I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: change the NAME of the two applications and use different IDs/PACKAGE NAMEs for both in config.xml file. If your applications share the same package name, it will simply overwrite the old app with new app of same package name.

Comment: paste your **config.xml's** widget tag of both app like `<widget id="com.ionicframework.app">`

Comment: I found this which explains it: https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/makeyourionicappunique